# Task asynchronous pattern with sockets

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to implement a class that can listen for incoming TCP data. I am trying to do so using tasks.

I have two central methods

```
    private async void ReceiveAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int bytesRead = await Receive();

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                byte[] result = new byte[bytesRead];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, result, 0, bytesRead);

                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
    private Task<int> Receive()
    {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (sock.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                    if (sock.Available > 0)
                        return sock.Receive(_buffer, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                return -1;
            }
            );
    }
```

In my main program, I call `ReceiveAsync()` and then send some data down the TCP pipeline, to which the receiver responds. I do get this reply, but now I am caught in an endless loop inside the `while(true)`, and further data sent from the "receiver" is not being received.

There is something completely wrong. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
int bytesRead;
do {
    bytesRead = await Receive();

    if(bytesRead > 0) {...}
} while (bytesRead > 0);
```

i.e. use `bytesRead` as an exit condition.

Also: you can probably use async here very nicely:

```
// for illustration ONLY
TaskCompletionSource<int> source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
sock.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ar =>
{
    try
    {
        int val = ((Socket)ar.AsyncState).EndReceive(ar);
        source.SetResult(val);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        source.SetException(ex);
    }
}, sock);
return source.Task;
```

Comment: Using bytesRead as en exit condition will effectively stop my listening. If data is sent at a later time, I will not be able to receive that. My point is to constantly having something (thread or IOCP) to listen to incoming data.

Comment: @lejon if a socket or network stream returns zero, it means the socket has closed. No more data will **ever** arrive. The Begin* in my answer achieves the IOCP effect.

Comment: yes of course. Thanks for reminding me. How come your code is only for illustration?

Comment: @lejon mainly because I haven't handled all the same cases you did - i.e. "this may need some tweaks"; for example, I haven't done any socket polling in this example. I didn't want you thinking it was 1:1 functionally identical